# Extend recursive (library) function without code duplication

Tags: python, function, recursion

is it possible to extend a recursive function such that one can break out of it python without duplicating the code? To be more specific, I have a function of the following form:

```py
# some library

def collate(batch):
    if isinstance(batch[0], (list, tuple)):
        return [collate(s) for s in batch]
    elif isinstance(batch[0], float):
        return np.array(batch)
    # ...
    
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Now I would like to extend this function in the following manner

```py
# my code
import library


def mod_collate(batch):
    if isinstance(batch[0], MyFunnyClass):
        return batch
    else:
        return library.collate(batch)
```

Now the issue is, once I am in the else condition of `mod_collate` one can never break out of the original collate function. I.e. if batch is something like:

```
f1 = MyFunnyClass()
f2 = MyFunnyClass()

batch = ([1., f1], [2., f2])
```

batch[0] will be of instance list, therefore falling back to the original collate function and from there can not break out and use my extension.
Or is the only solution to rewrite collate as a class and then subclass it?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it easily unless original `collate` was designed with extending it in mind. What happens in the last `else` clause of `collate` (the default that matches anything else)?

Comment: The else clause has a raise NotImplementedError ...

Comment: In that case I would opt to move it to your codebase and extend it as you wish. There are some hacky ways to extend it without rewriting the code but they can lead to hard to debug errors and the readability would suffer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved like the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module is extensible to serialize unknown types:

> If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized.

You can make your `collate` function more flexible by accepting a `default` argument:

```py
def collate(batch, default=None):
    if isinstance(batch[0], (list, tuple)):
        return [collate(s, default) for s in batch]
    elif isinstance(batch[0], float):
        return np.array(batch)
    # ...
    if default is not None:
        return default(batch)
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Your `mod_collate` function would now look like:

```
def funny_collate(batch):
    if isinstance(batch[0], MyFunnyClass):
        return batch
    raise NotImplementedError


def mod_collate(batch):
    """This function may not even be usefull, better call callate directly with the fault argument.
    """
    return collate(batch, default=funny_collate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant suggestion of doing this. Unfortunately, it is not really a solution as default_collate is a library function that I can not edit.